# How to get x,y coordinates of turtlebot

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to get the x and y coordinates of a turtlebot in the simulated world. Currently I have subscribed to the odom topic and have been able to get pose.pose.position.x and pose.pose.position.y. However when I get these values they are not x=0 and y=0 as I expect as the turtlebot has not yet moved. Is there something wrong with my assumption and/or am I not using the right rostopic to get desired x and y values?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317343/how-to-get-x,y-coordinates-of-turtlebot/) by [GroggyROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/39965/groggyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:
Why did you delete and close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So what are the values you see, instead of `0, 0`? Keep in mind that a simulator typically uses numerical approximations that may result in drift even though the model should be at rest/idle.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GroggyROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/39965/groggyros/) on 2019-03-03**:
When I run "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch "

x: -1.05240047001e-06
y: 8.27266784267e-07